# What happens when a router does not find the gateway?

Tags: network-interface, ethernet

What happens when a router does not find the proper destination network from routing table? Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to U&L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming we're talking about TCP/IP here.

The router will use its default route if one is defined.  Otherwise it should drop the packet and send an ICMP 'destination unreachable' message to the originator.